# How to close connection when page closed and reloaded? (reactjs)

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem with my asp.net core and reactjs app.
I want to fire `OnDisconnected` method in backend side but I dont know how and when I can call this method?

This is my react code :

```
useEffect(() => {
    const newConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('https://localhost:5032/hub/notif',
        {
          accessTokenFactory: () =>Token
        })
      .withAutomaticReconnect()
      .build();

    setConnection(newConnection);
    console.log(newConnection);
  }, []);

  useEffect(async () => {
    if (connection) {
      connection.start()
        .then(result => {
          console.log('Connected!');

          connection.on('RecieveNotification', message => {
            console.log(message);
          });
        })
        .catch(e => console.log('Connection failed: ', e));
    }
  }, [connection]);
```

Comment: you can pass callback function into `useEffect` that will be called on component dismount... its passed in return value: `useEffect(()=>{something(); return ()=>disconnect();,[])` i dont know if it helps

Comment: Thank you but it did not work.

Comment: To close/dispose the Asp.net core SignalR connection, you can try to use the StopAsync and DisposeAsync method, code like this: `try{ await hubConnection.StopAsync(); } catch (Exception exception) { Logger.LogInformation(exception.Message);} finally { await hubConnection.DisposeAsync();}`

Comment: OnDisconnected on dotnet core app does not work when I close react app window or reload it.

Comment: Yes, since you are enabling the Automatically reconnect (`. withAutomaticReconnect()`), after close the page, it will automatically reconnect to the server. Refer to [Automatically reconnect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#automatically-reconnect).